# Android google maps fragment issue

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, maps

I am implementing Google maps in my android app. It works well but sometimes the app crashes and gives me this error: (Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2 in Error inflating class fragment).
I tried all solutions suggested but most of them are old and I still has the same issue.
Can you please help me with this issue while it still cause app crash.

this is the code used in Google Maps:

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityTruckLocationBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        lat=lang="0";

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map2);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        LatLng myplace = new LatLng(29.2722744, 47.8585885);
        //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myplace).title("Marker in myplace"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myplace,11));
        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapLongClick(@NonNull LatLng latLng) {
                lat=String.valueOf(latLng.latitude);
                lang=String.valueOf(latLng.longitude);
                redirect();
            }
        });

    }
    public void redirect(){
        Intent intent=new Intent(TruckLocation.this,Truck_Profile.class);
        intent.putExtra("intenttype","location");
        intent.putExtra("lat",lat);
        intent.putExtra("lang",lang);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

Here is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map2"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TruckLocation" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue in TruckLocationActivity.xml , you can share this xml with us to help you .

Comment: I added the XML code @mohamed-saad

Comment: try to use this >>> 

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         />

Comment: I still have the issue